# MongoError: cannot do queries on admin in atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I just set up a free MongoDB on Atlas. I added a database called 'react-project' that I'm trying to connect to using mongoose. Here is my connection string:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://myUser:myPassword@myCluster.mongodb.net/react-project');
```

As you can see, at the end of the query I specify the database I want to connect to. I can connect to the mongodb instance just fine, but when I try and do an operation (such as Model.find()), I get the following MongoError:

```
MongoError: cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas
```

This leads me to believe that it is not connecting to the 'react-project' database, but is connecting to the 'admin' database instead.

Why is this happening and how can I connect to the correct database?

Here is the code I'm running that is giving me the error:

```
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productId: Number,
    img: String,
    price: Number,
    title: String,
    type: String
});

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

// Return all products
Product.find(function(error,result) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Seems like its a new one.

Heres my connection string that now works

mongoose.connect('mongodb://**USERNAME**:**PASSWORD**@*myShard*-shard-00-00-lbofd.mongodb.net:27017,*myShard*-shard-00-01-lbofd.mongodb.net:27017,*myShard*-shard-00-02-lbofd.mongodb.net:27017/**MYDBNAME**?ssl=true&replicaSet=*myShard*-shard-0&authSource=admin');

To create a new DB I used MongoDB Compass. Copy the connection string from the Atlas site(the longer one - 3.4 I believe), when you open mongodb compass it will recognize that there is a connection string in your clipboard (OSX) and will allow you to populate the connection for Compass with a simple click. You can create a new Database from there (Click on MyCluster at top left - then Create Database. Put the name of the new db in the bolded MYDBNAME in my connection string.

It did take a few refreshes to see new data.

I had much the same connection string as you (db name/shard different etc) - I was able to POST but not GET. POSTS didnt create error (but I could not find data I posted) and GET threw the same error as you got.

Answer (score 12):

I just got this error after trying to switch from my paid Mongo Atlas cluster back to my free cluster.  The solution for me ended up being blissfully simple:

In the URI, I changed `/admin` to the name of the free cluster's db  or `/test` in my case.

String before fix:

```
"mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-azhuz.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

String after fix:

```
"mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-azhuz.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue, none of the above helped.  Documenting my solution since this page is the first hit on Google.

If you're using the connect-mongo library like I was, you can fix it by using the older connection string (Node 2.2 not Node 3.0).  To get that in Atlas, Click on your cluster -> Connect -> Connect Your Application -> under driver choose node v. 2.2 and copy that connection string.

This is because connect-mongo can't handle the "+srv" in the newer strings.

So that string should look like

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-rnmsm.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-rnmsm.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-rnmsm.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Answer (score 5):

Got the same issue. 
Changing connection string to **3.4 version** (the longer one instead of 3.6) helped. 
Strange, it had worked well on it on 3.6 before the issue appeared.

Comment: this helped me too :) changed nothing but the connection string. Now it is a lot longer but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem. Just change the ***/admin*** to your **Cluster name** in MongoURL.
Example: 
mongodb+srv://**UserName**:**Password**@cluster0-qkaef.mongodb.net/**ClusterName**?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue using the Serverless Framework and AWS Lambda. My issue was that the environment variables were not being updated with my `deploy` command and it was using an older version of my Atlas connection string with an out-dated user with incorrect permissions.

So while that was a specific occurrence of my error, for other users that run into this, it seems like it could also just be a permissions issue with the user.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution on a different website, but decided to share it here!

Basically, substitute `/admin` in the connection string to the name of your cluster in MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you following this step. (my **node** version v10.15.0, **mongodb compass** Version 1.16.3 (1.16.3))

1. Make Sure your user have right [readWriteAnyDatabase@admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Adq.jpg)
2. then copy
   `mongodb+srv://<yourUsername>:<yourPassword>@devconnector-xszss.mongodb.net/admin`
3. after you copy when open mongoDB Compass will display the [alert prop like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIOBO.png) then click connect button
4. after login [create the new database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRwAS.png). In this case my database that I already create is name **devconnector**.
5. then in your [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3DzD.png) (in this case my app is using **Nodejs**) and make sure that in the url `mongodb+srv://<yourUsername>:<yourPassword>@devconnector-xszss.mongodb.net/YourdatabseYouJustCreate` in my case the database that I just created is **devconnector**. make sure it is not **admin**
6. then you can make a [post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyOUN.png). [(my post request code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXhLS.png). [my UserSchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFLzj.png)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's really late to answer this but I was having the same problem and I just put **Mongodb user name after a '/'** now my connection string looks like `mongodb+srv://UddeshRW:uddesh@cluster0-2erky.mongodb.net/<Mongodb user name>`

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I don't remember how I fixed this issue myself so I just marked the most upvoted answer at the time, even though I remember it wasn't exactly how I solved it.

Comment: Most of the time It happens with me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using mongoose. Banged my head against the wall for an hour, until I rechecked the [mongoose docs.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

the `.connect()` method has a second parameter to specify to use the new url parser for mongo :)

Hope this helps someone (or my future self)!

Answer (score 0):

Your connection URL can be any of the two:

1.

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<pasword>@<your replica set>.mongodb.net/<your database name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

2. 

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<pasword>@<your replica set>.mongodb.net/<your database name>?authSource=admin&replicaSet=portal-shard-0&readPreference=primary&ssl=true
```

your replical set will be there automatically,
those you need to supply to your connection string are username, password and database name
so change the admin in your URL to one of your database name

Your username and password is the username and password of the user your created under Database Access in your mongo dashboard sidebar