# Cannot do raw queries on admin API doesn't work on MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

My api server wrote with `Node.js` , database is `MongoDB`.

API works fine in my local.

When I push the same data to `MongoDB Atlas` and push my api server to `Heroku`

```
MongoDB version 4.2
```

Call the API I get the error

```
{"error":"cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas"}
```

API:
https://movie-with-atlas.herokuapp.com/api/getTwRanking

My API server code about connect to MongoDB Atlas:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    // MongoDB Atlas
    mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://myAccount:myPassword@cluster0.vcwmp.mongodb.net/movietogo?retryWrites=true&w=majority' , { useNewUrlParser: true });

    // if connect with my local API is fine
    // mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/movietogo');
}
```

I have checked my Network Access on MongoDB Atlas, set `0.0.0.0/0 (includes your current IP address)` for `Heroku`, the issue still exists.

[image]

How do I fix my connect with MongoDB Atlas issue ? Thanks.

It comes from my API code:

I search the collection TwRanking and find the object key `theater` is TwRanking

```
getTwRanking (req, res, next) {
    console.log('check getTwRanking');
    const cityCollection = mongoose.model("TwRanking", MovieSchema, "TwRanking");

    cityCollection.find({ "theater": "TwRanking" })
         .then(movie => res.send(movie))
         .catch(next);
},
```

I guess it catchs the error.

If look the answer [MongoError: cannot do queries on admin in atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023507/mongoerror-cannot-do-queries-on-admin-in-atlas)

connect code change like this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://myAccount:myPassword@cluster0-shard-00-00.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.vcwmp.mongodb.net:27017/movietogo?ssl=true&replicaSet=cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin');
```

I will get the error:

```
GET https://movie-with-atlas.herokuapp.com/api/getTwRanking 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Comment: Where is this error coming from and what are you doing that causes it?

Comment: This is a duplicate question.
Go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023507/mongoerror-cannot-do-queries-on-admin-in-atlas

Comment: @D.SM
It comes from my API query code, I update it in question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoError: cannot do queries on admin in atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023507/mongoerror-cannot-do-queries-on-admin-in-atlas)

Comment: No, I have tried it before I post my question, if I set the three shared like the answerr, I will get error `GET https://movie-with-atlas.herokuapp.com/api/getTwRanking 503 (Service Unavailable)`.